# POST API Request - Only Print if JSON Data in Response Has Changed - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create an way to actively monitor sales/listings.  I have a created POST api that will call the website and it currently is successfully pulling down the JSON data that has the item that sold, the price, the time, seller, and buyer.

Here's an example of the data returned in the JSON.

Item: 1

Price: 50$

Sold Date: 10/28/2021 10:00AM

Seller: John

Buyer: Frank

Say this script runs every 5 minutes and prints out the last sale.  At 10:05, it sees Item 1 sold so it prints out the data.  At 10:10, no new items sold, so it prints out Item 1 again.  I am looking for a way to only print out if Item 2 sells(aka updated JSON data), but I am having trouble figuring out the best way to handle this logic in python.

Would you just use date/time minus the last 5mins?  Or is there a better way?

Code is simple:

```
asset_url = 'www.sample.com/api/'

seller_payload = json.dumps({
  "name": "find",
  "arguments": [
    {
      "database": "prod",
      "data": "SALES",
      "query": {
        "seller": {
          "$in": [
            "sellerid"
          ]
        },
      },
      "sort": {
        "epoch": {
          "$numberInt": "-1"
        }
      },
      "limit": {
          "$numberInt": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "service": "db"
})

seller_response = requests.request("POST", asset_url, headers=profile_headers, data=seller_payload)

asset_id = seller_response[0]['asset']
seller = seller_response[0]['seller']
price = seller_response[0]['price']
print(asset_id)
print(seller)
print(price)
```

Comment: Give and example of your code please, because the answer to this question depends on how your code looks.

Comment: Think about creating a class containing every sale information (Every transaction is an instance), then create a list that holds the transaction class. Print the last element added.

Comment: I added some example code

Comment: Is a class necessary?  My request only ever returns the last value (the last item sold).

Answer (score 0):

If the script runs every 5 minutes, store each transaction in a file. Something like this:

```
from pickle import dump, loads
    
transactions = []
try:
    transactions = loads("transactions.txt") # try to read transactions from file.
except:
    print("An exception occurred.")
# Check if the last transaction is the same as it was five minutes ago.
if (not (transactions[-1]["asset"] == seller_response[0]["asset"] && transactions[-1]["seller"] == seller_response[0]["seller"] && transactions[-1]["soldDate"] == seller_response[0]["soldDate"] && transactions[-1]["buyer"] == seller_response[0]["buyer"] && transactions[-1]["item"] == seller_response[0]["item"])):
    print(seller_response[0])
    transactions.push(seller_response[0])
    dump(transactions,"transactions.txt")
```